# Testing internal Flux.interval

Tags: java, unit-testing, project-reactor

I want to provide some data using Reactor's Flux. Since it may take a lot of time to provide this data, I decided to introduce a ping mechanism (e.g. to keep tcp connection alive and not get timeouts). Here is my simplified solution:

```
public class Example {

    private final DataProvider dataProvider;

    public Example(DataProvider dataProvider) {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    public Flux<String> getData() {
        AtomicBoolean inProgress = new AtomicBoolean(true);

        Flux<String> dataFlux = dataProvider.provide()
            .doFinally(ignoreIt -> inProgress.set(false));

        return dataFlux.mergeWith(ping(inProgress::get));
    }

    private Publisher<String> ping(Supplier<Boolean> inProgress) {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1), Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .map((tick) -> "ping " + tick)
                .takeWhile(ignoreIt -> inProgress.get());
    }

    interface DataProvider {
        Flux<String> provide();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Callable<String> dataProviderLogic = () -> {
            Thread.sleep(3500);
            return "REAL DATA - SHOULD TERMINATE PING";
        };

        // wrapping synchronous call
        DataProvider dataProvider = () -> Mono.fromCallable(dataProviderLogic)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flux();

        new Example(dataProvider).getData()
            .doOnNext(data -> System.out.println("GOT: " + data))
            .blockLast();
    }
}
```

Above code prints on console:

```
GOT: ping 0
GOT: ping 1
GOT: ping 2
GOT: REAL DATA - SHOULD TERMINATE PING
```

So it works as expected.

The question is: **how can I test this ping mechanism in a Junit5 test, so it won't take a lot of time** (e.g. several seconds)**?**

In an ideal world I would like to write a test which imitates a delay for the data provision, check if expected number of pings was generated and verify if complete signal was emitted (to make sure that ping flux terminates as expected). Of course I would like to have a unit test, which can be run in ms.

I tried this, but with no luck:

```
    @Test
    void test() {
        TestPublisher<String> publisher = TestPublisher.create();

        Flux<String> data = new Example(publisher::flux).getData();

        StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> data)
                .thenAwait(Duration.ofMillis(3500))
                .then(() -> publisher.emit("REAL DATA - SHOULD TERMINATE PING"))
                .then(publisher::complete)
                .expectNextCount(4)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
```

Above test ends up with this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNextCount(4)" failed (expected: count = 4; actual: counted = 1; signal: onComplete())
```

Is it possible at all to use virtual time for internally created Flux.interval?

Any ideas for an alternative *ping* solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite of the fact that above ping mechanism is not the best one (I suggest to use `Sink` instead of `AtomicBoolean` and use `takeUntilOther` instead of `takeWhile`), in my case the problem was probably related to the situation where not all flux instructions were wrapped with `withVirtualTime`. This code works as expected in the above case:

```
    @Test
    void test() {
        StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> {
            Flux<String> data = Flux.just("REAL DATA - SHOULD TERMINATE PING").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(3200));
            return new Example(() -> data).getData();
        })
                .thenAwait(Duration.ofMillis(3500))
                .expectNextCount(4)
                .thenAwait(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .verifyComplete();
    }
```